# C++ Unable to convert vector<char> to int

Tags: c++

I am using boost ASIO to send message over TCP stream. I send the body size first in strictly 4 bytes length. Than on server side I make a `vector<char>` which I resize to 4 bytes and I put the message body size there.
Here is how I convert vector of char `std::vector<char> size;` to int:

```
_packet.body_size = static_cast<int>(_packet.size[0]);
```

This scenario works when the value which is kept inside `_packet.size[0]` is not bigger of 124.

[image]

And in this scenario works. `body_size` is set to `124` as you can see.

However if the value gets bigger than `124` like `128` for example I am not able to parse it correctly in the same way as I did with `124`.

Take a look:

[image]

See to what number is set `body_size`. Why am I not able to convert bigger than 124 numbers?

Where is mistake and how can I fix it?

Comment: signed `char` value range is from -128 to 127. Try `unsigned char` instead?

Comment: You can't store 128 in a signed 8 bit integer (the usual default for `char`)

Comment: now I am curious if you also tried `125`, `126` and `127`

Comment: If you want your `int` to be composed of all 4 `char` values in the vector, then your simple cast won't work (it just casts the value of the first element). You'll need something more devious, like: `_packet.body_size = *(reinterpret_cast<int*>(_packet.size.data()));`. I'm not (yet) recommending that, but can you clarify?

Comment: @AdrianMole it worked. Doing this `*(reinterpret_cast<int*>(_packet.size.data()));` seem to solved the problem completely. Why is that? Can you make an complete answer?

Comment: @Venelin It will work *sometimes* on *some* platforms using *some* compilers. If I post just that as an answer, it will (justifiably) attract (lots of) downvotes.

Comment: Okay thank what can I do to make it work in other cases as well? Can you make such answer ?

Comment: Use `unsigned char` for arbitrary binary data. `char` can be either signed or unsigned, and (as you have noticed) the signed version can cause strange surprises.

Answer (score 2):

To construct a (4-byte/32-bit) integer from the 4 single-byte `char` values in your vector, and to do so *safely*, you will need to 'mask-in' each character into the relevant 8 bits of that integer.

You can do this using a combination of bitwise or (`|`) and bit-shift (`<<`) operations in a short loop:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> cVec = { -128, 0, 0, 0 };
    int32_t iVal = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        iVal |= static_cast<int>(cVec[i]) << (i * 8);
    }
    std::cout << iVal << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The above will work for systems that use [Little-Endian byte sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) for integers (most common processors, like the Intel x86/x64 family, use this system). On Big-Endian systems, you will need to add the bytes in reverse order, using the following as the 'body' of the `for` loop:

```cpp
        iVal |= static_cast<int>(cVec[3-i]) << (i * 8);
```

---

Note: It may be tempting to just cast the address of the vector's data to a pointer-to-int and then dereference that (as I suggested in the comments). However, this is unsafe and introduces **undefined behaviour**, as it violates
the [Strict Aliasing Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7005988/10871073) of the C++ language.

Comment: Instead of fixing endianness "by hand", I'd use ntohl() here - that makes it easier to read and more portable. @Venelin: for the record, in a network packet the order is big-endian by convention, so your packet size would read {0,0,0,124} rather than {124,0,0,0}.

Comment: @Sander it is Little-Endian in my case. Can you make an answer with `ntohl` ?

Comment: On the sending system, simply create a new `int body_size_nbo = htonl(body_size);` and send out your frame with `body_size_nbo` rather than `body_size`. On the receiving side, read out the integer into `body_size_nbo` as described in the answers and then convert using `body_size = ntohl(body_size_nbo);`. That should make sure your code can be used on machines with any endianness.

Comment: @Sander The OP seems to have abandoned this question and reposted the same thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64439721/10871073) - borrowing some of the information the answerers have provided (though using that info incorrectly)!

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer the question:

You've extracted just the first byte, then converted it to an integer. If the subsequent bytes have meaningful information, they are "lost".

What you intended was to *reinterpret* all four bytes as an integer.

That would look like this:

```
_packet.body_size = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&_packet.size[0]);
```

However, the other answers are correct in that *this is not safe*. You cannot take a sequence of `char`s and pretend that an `int` object exists there. Contrary to popular belief, it's not "all just bytes".  (Though it will often appear to work on your system, to be fair.)

The safe approach is `std::memcpy`:

```
assert(packet.size.size() >= sizeof(_packet.body_size));
std::memcpy(&_packet.body_size, &packet.size[0], sizeof(_packet.body_size));
```

… or `std::copy`:

```
assert(packet.size.size() >= sizeof(_packet.body_size));
std::copy(
   packet.size.begin(),
   packet.size.end(),
   static_cast<char*>(&_packet.body.size)
);
```

This works because the opposite conversion (pretending an `int` is a sequence of `char`s) *is* valid and safe.

You'd be better off, though, just bitmasking in the individual bytes to get endian-safety (and to ensure `int` size mismatches don't kill you!), as Adrian has already shown.

Comment: Without wishing to challenge your answer (it's good, as far as it goes) ... but I'm curious as to what else other than *"all just bytes"* would be in the vector's data? ‎

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Asteroids With Wings. Can you please show an example about the better approach of `memcpy/std::copy` so the answer can provide the better approach as well ?

Comment: @Venelin There ya go (untested)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings so are memcpy and std::copy any good than or Adrian's approach is safer ?

Comment: Yes, like I said, you'd be better off with Adrian's approach. Though, if you _know_ that your `int` size and endianness is the same as on the platform that produced the vector in the first place, a quick `copy` is easier...

Comment: Well the size is prefixed by FlatBuffers. (https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/class_flat_buffers_1_1_flat_buffer_builder.html#a92de6a8a35e1ae5a07f5578bb0fda16c) and it's exactly 32bit which by my calculations is exactly 4 bytes. So In this case I believe it's fine

Comment: Okay, according to the FlatBuffers documentation, the data is always little-endian, so **if** your target platform is little-endian then the copy will work fine. Doesn't the library have a built-in way to do this, though?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223334/discussion-between-venelin-and-asteroids-with-wings).