# C++ Safe way to convert vector of char to size_t

Tags: c++

Here is my vector of char:

```
std::vector<char> size;
```

Here is the size_t value:

```
size_t body_size{0};
```

Here is how I convert `std::vector<char> size` to `size_t body_size`

```
_packet.body_size = *(reinterpret_cast<int*>(_packet.size.data()));
```

Is there another better/safer way to make the conversion?

Comment: Do you know the byte-order of the bytes in the vector? Is it the same as on your system? And please use `unsigned char` (or better yet `uint8_t` or even [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte)) for raw bytes.

Comment: You should also make sure that `size.length()` isn't smaller than `sizeof body_size`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you mean `uint8_t` instead of `size_t` ?

Comment: No, for the vector of bytes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've made `std::vector<std::byte> size;` and it works just fine. How can I convert from `std::vector<std::byte> size;` to `size_t body_size{0};` ?

Comment: Looks very like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64426995/10871073) and the answers given there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::memcpy(&body_size, &size[0], sizeof (body_size));`. That's safe.

Comment: If I do that instead of `_packet.body_size = *(reinterpret_cast<int*>(_packet.size.data()));` and I run it several times it gives me `Exception: std::bad_alloc` Do I need to do anything else before memcpy ?

Comment: Plus it gives some strange value for  `_packet.body_size`

Comment: Do you have enough bytes in your vector? You are probably overwriting some memory.

Comment: How can I prevent that @wilx ?

Comment: @Venelin reserve the memory for the vector first `std::vector<char> size(sizeof body_size);`